# Azure login request timeout after 1.5 hours

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a app that is hosted on Azure and uses Azure to handle login and creds etc. The app stays open and refreshes every 5 minutes. This works well for about 1.5 hours. Then when it does the usual auto refresh, no data gets returned. In dev tools, I can see that the request to the api returns a 200 but the expected payload is empty (during the refresh the page calls an internal API and returns data from a SQL db).

If I then hit F5, or click on any of the nav links, the site URL redirects to the microsoft login and then instantly redirects back to the page and everything works as expected. I dont have to enter creds again - it happens quickly.

I think there must be a token expiration issue maybe? It seems like the site needs to go and get new creds or set a new bearer token or something.
We have the token expiration set for much longer.

how can I fix this issue, I would like the page to be able to stay 'live' for 10 hours.

Comment: Does your app fit this authentication flow? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming , you are using Azure AD for authentication.I would suggest you to use refresh token to silently renew the access token.

Clients use access tokens to access a protected resource. An access token can be used only for a specific combination of user, client, and resource. Access tokens cannot be revoked and are valid until their expiry. A malicious actor that has obtained an access token can use it for extent of its lifetime. Adjusting the lifetime of an access token is a trade-off between improving system performance and increasing the amount of time that the client retains access after the user’s account is disabled. Improved system performance is achieved by reducing the number of times a client needs to acquire a fresh access token. **`The default is 1 hour - after 1 hour, the client must use the refresh token to (usually silently) acquire`** a new refresh token and access token.

Further reference , please visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) link.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks - Yeah this is the route I ended up taking.
Its a tricky one to solve.

Comment: Glad to know it worked. Please accept as an answer if it helped, it will help others who have the same requirement.